# Implement dynamic data model with MongoDB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I'm creating an application consisting of a bunch of entries. These entries are going to have a bunch of fields (e.g. category, name, description etc.) and be of a certain type (category). So the user would first create a category with a title and description and then define what other fields an entry in that category can and should have.

Example:

1. Create category, title => 'Books', description => 'A description'. Defining extra fields, author (required), image (not required).
2. Create entry, when choosing category => 'Books' the form is regenerated and the fields for author and image are shown with validation defined in the category.

I hope somebody understands..

I was talking to a friend about this who recommended going for MongoDB in order to implement this, now I have an app installed with Mongoid and everything works just fine.

The question is, how would I implement this in the best way, making it as flexible as possible?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to answer to your because it is quite vague… here is what I can say about MongoDB:
MongoDB is already as flexible as possible (that is even its problem actually).
The problem is more likely to sometime restricts its flexibility i.e. check access rights, check that your jSON you are storing is in the right scheme and so on.
If your db is not too huge and you do not want to bother with many collections, you can store all your Books items (documents) (or even a document containing lists) into the same collection.